# make list python have key pair

Tags: python

I have

```
list('327VUQ56156TX374');
['3', '2', '7', 'V', 'U', 'Q', '5', '6', '1', '5', '6', 'T', 'X', '3', '7', '4']
```

I want to get the array associative like this , its index.`[ 1=>'3',... 16=>'4' ]`

anyone can tell me please thanks

Comment: As a side note: I commented an answer, now my comment has vanished... why?

Comment: Note that using such index is not so different as using the string directly. What I mean is that you can access to characters exactly as you would have done with the array, and even directly from the string: `'327VUQ[...]'[3]` would return `V`, exactly as `result_dict[3]` would have done. So maybe you're not really wanting an array here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
dict(enumerate('327VUQ56156TX374'))
```

If you want starting count from 1 (and have a good reason for this :-)), you can use this (but it's only for >= 2.6)

```
dict(enumerate('327VUQ56156TX374', start=1))
```

Comment: Nice, I was unaware of the start argument for enumerate.

Comment: You don't really need to use `list` as `enumerate` works perfectly well on the string. `dict(enumerate('327VUQ56156TX374', start=1))`

Answer (score 2):

I think enumerate will do what you want:

```
>>> data = list('327VUQ56156TX374')
>>> [(i+1,d) for i,d in enumerate(data)]
[(1, '3'), (2, '2'), (3, '7'), (4, 'V'), (5, 'U'), (6, 'Q'), (7, '5'), (8, '6'), (9, '1'), (10, '5'), (11, '6'), (12, 'T'), (13, 'X'), (14, '3'), (15, '7'), (16, '4')]
>>> dict((i+1,d) for i,d in enumerate(data))
{1: '3', 2: '2', 3: '7', 4: 'V', 5: 'U', 6: 'Q', 7: '5', 8: '6', 9: '1', 10: '5', 11: '6', 12: 'T', 13: 'X', 14: '3', 15: '7', 16: '4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you referring to associative array? (a.k.a. dictionaries in python)

```
In [4]: dict((n+1, l) for n, l in enumerate('327VUQ56156TX374'))
Out[4]: 
{1: '3',
 2: '2',
 3: '7',
 4: 'V',
 5: 'U',
 6: 'Q',
 7: '5',
 8: '6',
 9: '1',
 10: '5',
 11: '6',
 12: 'T',
 13: 'X',
 14: '3',
 15: '7',
 16: '4'}
```